# How to perform division in Hive with a Select statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, division

I'm writing this in Hive.  I have a table that just holds one number.  I'll call the table that holds the number table_number and the actual number is `my_number`.

In a different table that doesn't yet exist, I need to enter a decimal number that is `1/my_number`.

I have tried `SELECT CAST((1/(SELECT my_number FROM table_number)) as double);`  I get a parse exception `"cannot recognize input near 'cast' '(' '('`

I've also tried `double(1/(SELECT my_number FROM table_number));`  I get another parse exception `"cannot recognize input near 'double' '(' 'Select'`

I'm at a total loss as to how to do this.  Can anyone give me some division examples that also use a select statement for one of the numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line should be

```
SELECT 1/CAST(my_number as double) FROM table_number;
```

Although I think it will be cast implicitly if you just do

```
SELECT 1/my_number FROM table_number;
```